# how to save and retrieve videoview obj state in activity

Tags: android

I am new to android.

I have **3 activities**. Each activity contains its **own thread**.

The thread is mainly used for playing the video in `videoview` for some specific time(1min). If the timer elapses(for ex,1min) then I call `videoview1.pause()` and start another(second) activity.

The second activity contains its own thread and is used for playing his own video in `videoview`. If  the timer elapses(for ex,1min) then I call `videoview2.pause()` and start another(third) activity.

The third activity contains its own thread and is used for playing the his own video in `videoview`. If  the timer elapses(for ex,1min) then I call `videoview3.pause()` and start another(first) activity. And so on...

The problem is when the third activity calls the first activity. The first thread plays the video from starting onwards. It's not playing the video after the pause i.e.(1min 1sec).

How to fix the problem? If you know any one please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, i am also having this kind problem. please let me know if you find any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to save the context. Try this link for reference: [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)